# Web/Network/Penetration testing open source tools

Tags: security, cloud-security

I am currently using ZAP for web application security scan.

Also, using Scout2 and Prowler for cloud auditing for infrastructure security.

I am checking Telnet open port, nmap, wireshark for network security.

Please share other open source tools which you find useful in your experience.
It will help me to identify and try with tools which already being using by you

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

We had used online web scan like: https://pentest-tools.com/

Comment: Thanks iamnoten .. I am already using same .. Thanks for sharing so others can implement in their project .. voting you up :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Web Application testing, IronWASP. The swiss army knife for web security testing

https://ironwasp.org/

Only downside is you need a Windows environment and does not run natively with Linux/MacOS. You might need Wine/CrossOver respectively.

A nice tool for network related security testing is Kali Linux.

Personaly, I prefer to use an integrated [security test](https://www.ixiacom.com/products/network-security-testing-breakingpoint) tool like Ixia's BreakingPoint, which can test and validate security components and architecture, simulate attacks and determine whether your devices will detect an issue.

Of course it's not open source and as such, you get what you pay for.

Full disclosure, I work as a Marketing Engineer at Ixia.